# How to detect if a paperclip attachment was changed in after_save callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

It looks like Paperclip doesn't honor the ActiveRecord dirty model. How do I detect the change in `after_save` callback.

```
class User

  has_attachment :avatar    
  after_save :do_something

  def do_something
    if name_changed?
      #
    end

    # How to determine avatar was changed?
    #if avatar_changed?
    #  #
    #end

  end
end
```

**Note**

I know I can detect the change in `before_save` callback using `avatar.dirty?` call, but the `dirty` flag is set to false after save.

I can add a processor, but I need to perform my actions after the model data is saved.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could try accessing the `_changed?` method for one of the attributes:

```
if avatar_updated_at_changed?
  # do something
end
```

Comment: This is what I am doing right now. I am wondering if there is a better method.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a better solution?

Answer (score 5):

When I need access to this data after save, I typically take this approach:

```
class Foo

  has_attachment :avatar
  before_save :check_for_avatar_changes
  after_save :do_something

  def do_something
    if @avatar_has_changes
      #
    end
  end

  def check_for_avatar_changes
    @avatar_has_changes = self.avatar.dirty?
  end

end
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post please include how/why your post will solve the problem.

Comment: There's a problem in the code of check_for_avatar_changes... If the funtion returns false, the model won't get saved, because it's a before_save callback.